# In what situations does a cantrip count as a half-level spell v.s. a 0 level spell

Tags: pathfinder-1e

When is a cantrip's spell level treated as 0, and when is it treated as 1/2?

Comment: Are you looking for specific cases, a general rule, or both?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think it's a specific case thing, but I'm not sure cause it's not showing up where I thought it would (the scroll table, for example, lists 0-level scrolls as 12.5 gp, but doesn't actually make any mention in the text that 0-level spells should count as 1/2 level) so maybe there is a general rule I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### When estimating a magic item's value, 0-level spells count as 1/2-level spells

[Table: Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values) at the bottom on Spell Level says, "A 0-level spell is half the value of a 1st-level spell for determining price." The table provides guidelines for estimating other kinds of magic items—like scrolls and wands—as well as wondrous items. [Scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Creating-Scrolls) and [wands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Creating-Wands) in particular—unless the GM rules otherwise—hew to the table's estimate.

Most other times—like when a wizard prepares [cantrips](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/#TOC-Cantrips)—0-level spells count as *actual* 0-level spells rather than a 1/2-level spells.

Comment: Is it really just that table?  Your linked scroll and wand sections, for example, make no mention of such a rule beyond a disagreement between their tabulated examples (which use the correct, 1/2 level, pricing) and their text (which makes no mention of anything like that).  I'm asking because that table is very often ignored in our games (its estimates are... not great) and it seems strange to have such an important rule only in such a weird spot.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I don't know what to tell you, man, except that *D&D 3.5e*, from a cursory search, is no better, so far as I can tell it not seeming to mention that 0-level-spells-count-as-1/2-level-spells thing in its description of wands *et al.* either. Also, I wouldn't necessarily call this a *disagreement*; not all omissions are, by nature, disagreements.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer **Probably Not Worth Adding to the Answer:** The *Player's Handbook* on Item Creation Feats makes the same claim: "A 0-level spell is considered to have a spell level of 1/2 for the purpose of" making some magic items (88).

Answer (score 5):

A 0-level spell’s spell level is treated as ½ when the rules text explicitly says it is, and at no other time. So unless you see a statement telling you to treat it as ½, treat it as 0.

The most notable place where the spell level of 0-level spells is treated as ½ is in the pricing of magic items, but this is not the only place.